# Cocoa: How to get a music file's Disc Number tag?

Tags: cocoa, audio

Right now i can get these tags from an audio file:

```
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Artist                        "artist"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Album                         "album"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Tempo                         "tempo"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_KeySignature                  "key signature"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_TimeSignature                 "time signature"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_TrackNumber                   "track number"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Year                          "year"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Composer                      "composer"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Lyricist                      "lyricist"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Genre                         "genre"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Title                         "title"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_RecordedDate                  "recorded date"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Comments                      "comments"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_Copyright                     "copyright"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_SourceEncoder                 "source encoder"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_EncodingApplication           "encoding application"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_NominalBitRate                "nominal bit rate"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_ChannelLayout                 "channel layout"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_ApproximateDurationInSeconds  "approximate duration in seconds"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_SourceBitDepth                "source bit depth"
#define kAFInfoDictionary_ISRC                          "ISRC"                  // International Standard Recording Code
#define kAFInfoDictionary_SubTitle                      "subtitle"
```

So how can i get the Disc Number tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TagLib: http://taglib.github.io/

It's free and powerful.